# Flutter: CRUD clarifications over Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been working on a little project on flutter since I just started learning it **a week ago** and I'm just wondering how I could retrieve a specific snippet of data from Firebase's `Firestore` database.

Here is the code on the relevant files:

`database.dart`

```
import 'package:plannus/models/user.dart';

class DatabaseMethods {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseMethods({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection("users");


  Future<void> updateUserData(String name, String handle) async {
    print(uid);
    return await users.document(uid).updateData({
      'name' : name,
      'handle' : handle,
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateSpecificUserData(String uid, String name, String handle) async {
    print(uid);
    return await users.document(uid).updateData({
      'name' : name,
      'handle' : handle,
    });
  }

  Future<Set<Set<String>>> getUserData() {
    return users.document(uid).get().then((value) => {
      if (value.exists) {
        value.data['handle']
      }
    });
  }

  void getSpecificUserData(String uid, String capture) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =  await users.document(uid).get();
    capture = snapshot.data['handle'];
    print(capture);
  }

  Future<String> retrieveData(String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await users.document(uid).get();
    Map<String, String> map = snap.data;
    String handle = map['name'];
    return handle;
  }
//
  uploadUserInfo(userMap) {
    Firestore.instance.collection("users").add(userMap);
  }


  // user data from snapshot
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get userInfo {
    return users.snapshots();
  }

}
```

`profile.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plannus/messages/database.dart';
import 'package:plannus/models/user.dart';
import 'package:plannus/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {

  final AuthService auth = AuthService();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // 'id' of form
  bool loading = false;
  // text field state
  String name = '';
  String password = '';
  String handle = '';
  String error = '';

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  QuerySnapshot currentUser;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    String handle = '';
    print(user.uid);
    Future<String> str = databaseMethods.retrieveData(user.uid);
    str.then((value) => {
      handle = value
    });
    print(handle);
      return new Scaffold(
//          appBar: AppBar(
//            title:
//          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
            child: Form(
              key: formKey, // keep track of form and its state
              child : Column (
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/profilepicture.png', height: 300, width: 300),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Name',
                      icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline, color: Colors.blue),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 2),
                      ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
                    )
                    ),
                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter your name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => name = val);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Handle',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.alternate_email, color: Colors.blue),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 2),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
                        )
                    ),
                    obscureText: false,
                    validator: (val) => val[0] != '@' ? 'Handle starts with @!' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() => handle = val);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        child: Text(
                          'Update',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            print(user.uid);
                            await databaseMethods.updateSpecificUserData(user.uid, name, handle);
                            setState(() {
                              error = 'Update successful!';
                            });
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                  Text(
                    error,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
      );
    }
}
```

My code can be real messy (for which I apologise because I have been stuck on this for a quite long time and have been rigorously attempting various methods to extract the data out).

**Ultimately, my main objective is to get the value(handle) from my data stored in firebase and then to dynamically display it on my appbar.**

My firebase database collection is named 'users' and carries only data { name: "...", handle: "..."}.

Thanks for bearing with my long post.

[Profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5qCv.png)

Comment: Hey all, I have tried adding using the method below and setting state in my ```build``` method, like this
`databaseMethods.getSpecificUserData(user.uid).then((value) => {
setState(() => handle = value)
 }); `, where the `.getSpecificUserData(user.uid)` is an implementation that returns the string desired but unfortunately the handle is not printed on the appbar.
Although the console prints the value in the handle numerous times(the print statement is in my `getSpecificUserData` method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get data from firebase's firestore. I think its best to rename your "name" as "n" to make the size of your data stored in the database smaller.

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(uid)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  username = ds["name"];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. But it returns a ```Future<String>```, so how to I extract that? I'm not too familiar with Dart unlike Java's asynchronous programming which has the join/get method to extract the value

Comment: @Rishi use the await keyword to extract the string like how I did it in the answer above. This video might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9Uk1Xou0m4&t=627s